# Weird iOS 5 Bug - UITextField setTextAlignment Does Not Work In iOS5

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5

I have keyboard with lots of languages, e.g. Hebrew, Arabic and English

This line works fine in iOS 4:

```
[cell.textField setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentRight];
```

But in iOS 5 it's not working - When I try to enter text in English I get right text alignment, but when I try to type in Hebrew or Arabic I get left text alignment.

Why is iOS 5 not applying my text alignment, and how should I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: I'm going to hazard a guess that this is because Hebrew & Arabic are right-to-left written languages, so iOS is automatically switching the alignment.

Comment: yes, when I'm typing a non english (hebrew arabic R to L) I get text on the left side, after I click done I get the text back to the right side, that is the issue that makes me crazy

Answer (score 1):

The command help says to use NSTextAlignment.

```
[yourTextField setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
```

that worked for me